# ¿Como modificar kwargs en Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy haciendo la página de confirmación de una compra y quiero pasarle un hash del identificador del pedido,previamente generado por el sistema, a una url y con un decorador comprobar si el usuario que está accediendo es propietario de ese pedido por un decorador.

Para agilizar la tarea quiero modificar el kwargs cambiando el hash por el pedido y así no tener que hacer una segunda búsqueda de ese pedido.

Esta es a la view que intento acceder:

### Clase

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(propietarioPedido, name='dispatch')
class ConfirmacionCompra(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'intranet/confirmacion_comprar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ConfirmacionCompra, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['perfil'] = perfil
        pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pedido'])
        context['pedido'] = pedido
        fotos = Foto.objects.filter(producto = pedido.producto)
        return context
```

Este es el decorador que estoy usando:

### Decorador

```
def propietarioPedido(funcion):

    def error():
        raise PermissionDenied

    def comprobarPropiedadPedido(request,*args,**kwargs):
        perfil = Perfil.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
        pedidos = Pedido.objects.filter(perfil = perfil)
        for p in pedidos:
            hash = hashlib.sha256(str(p.id).encode('utf-8'))
            if hash.hexdigest() == kwargs['pedido']:
                kwargs.update({'pedido': p.id})
                return funcion(request,*args,**kwargs)
        return error()

    return comprobarPropiedadPedido
```

Al hacer `print(kwargs)` en el decorador justo antes de return me devuelve `{'pedido': 8564}` pero al hacerlo en la view me devuelve `{'pedido':'9f14025af0065b30e47e23ebb3b491d39ae8ed17d33739e5ff3827ffb3634953'}`

### URL

```
url(r'^confirmacion_compra/(?P<pedido>[-\w]+)/$',
    intranet_views.ConfirmacionCompra.as_view(), name='confirmacion-compra'),
```

Comment: has probado haciendolo así:      kwargs['pedido'] = p.id ?

Comment: si y tampoco funciona.

Comment: No sé si estará relacionado, pues no uso django y no sé muy bien qué hace el decorador `@method_decorator` pero... en tu uso de ese decorador estás diciendo que decore el método `.dispatch()` con el método `propietarioPedido()`. Sin embargo no muestras el código de `dispatch()` ¿es ese el método que quieres decorar? ¿Es ese quien genera la "view" a que te refieres en la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Estás pasando algo al a URL? Tal vez algomo como `/?pedido=xxx` ?

Comment: no, le estoy mandando esto `/confirmacion_compra/9f14025af0065b30e47e23ebb3b491d39ae8ed17d33739e5ff3827ffb3634953/` modifico la pregunta y añado la url, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En Django existe algo que se llama dispatch(), que permite modificar, agregar o eliminar diferentes kwargs, o sus valores.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

```
def dispatch(self, pedido, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'pedido': pedido})
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

- En ese código dispatch obtiene el parámetro *(pedido)* de la url y lo asigna en una kwargs llamada pedido.

en el **get_context_data** también puedes obtener todas las kwargs a través de kwargs.get y después modificar su valor con kwargs.update.

```
    url_kwargs = kwargs.get('kwargs', {})
    pedido = url_kwargs.get('pedido')
    kwargs.update({'pedido': pedido})
```